# Regarding MS-Sync framework

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

with the help of  MS-Sync framework can i sync data between two sql server table in two different database. i hard  MS-Sync framework used to sync data between sql server & sql server CE database. give me url from where i can have the idea of sync data between two table in two different database.

Answer (score 0):

try this: [Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx), it should work with SQl